# Magento 2 Invalid block type Magento\Catalog\Block\Crosssellproduct

Tags: magento2, nginx, apache

Magento 2.2.6 - Apache - Nginx

I am getting this error when trying to open product pages on my site

> 2 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type:
>   Magento\Catalog\Block\Crosssellproduct Exception #1
>   (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Crosssellproduct does not exist

This site was working previously but some changes to either server or site files are causing this to happen.

Also is it possible this error is showing for something unrelated as I have read on other similar posts for this error?

Comment: Have you try to run the deploy and upgrade command?

Comment: Yes both have been run and permission set also for files and directories and user and group also set only product page is giving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because the block Magento\Catalog\Block\Crosssellproduct does not exist.

The layout tried to create the block however as this class did not exist it reported type error.

Comment: Yes however what can cause this to stop exisiting all of a sudden when it was working previously any ideas server or theme changes or permission related any setting that can be causing this

Comment: very dissapointed with the lack of help or suggestions on this

Comment: @jt9489, sorry for replying late - the above class does not exist in your specified version. A custom class, however, should not have such a name that looks like a core class. These are all I can tell about the problem.

Comment: thanks anybody else have any suggestions